# Please select at least one of the signature versions to use in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: java, apk

I have recently updated my Android Studio to version 2.3.3. When trying to Generate Signed APK I am getting the error message:

> Please select at least one of the signature versions to use

There are two options: **V1 (Jar Signature)** and **V2 (Full APK Signature)**.
I am not sure which one to choose. And what are the merits of choosing one over the other or choosing both?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this link: [signature help](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2)

APK Signature Scheme v2 offers:

1. Faster app install times
2. More protection against unauthorized alterations to APK files.

> Android 7.0 introduces APK Signature Scheme v2, a new app-signing
>   scheme that offers faster app install times and more protection
>   against unauthorized alterations to APK files. By default, Android
>   Studio 2.2 and the **Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2 sign your app using
>   both** APK Signature Scheme v2 and the traditional signing scheme, which
>   uses JAR signing.

It is **recommended** to use APK Signature Scheme **v2** but is **not mandatory**.

> Although we recommend applying APK Signature Scheme v2 to your app,
>   this new scheme is not mandatory. If your app doesn't build properly
>   when using APK Signature Scheme v2, you can disable the new scheme.

Answer (score 14):

Mark both Jar and Full Apk, this should give you a play store publishable signed apk.

[image]

I tried Full Apk Sign the first time but Publish Console did not accept that, selecting both options worked for me